# Transferring realtime data over a local network

Tags: java, android, memory-management

At the moment, I have a thread that is constantly sending data over a local network. Below is a snippet of the current code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(!interrupted()) {
        byte[] data = new byte[16];
        int b = 0;
        try {
            intToByteArray(acx[0][0], data, 0);
            intToByteArray(acx[0][1], data, 4);
            intToByteArray(acx[1][0], data, 8);
            for(int i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                if(btns[i] == 1)
                    b |= (int) Math.pow(2, i);
            }
            intToByteArray(b, data, 12);
            //sleep(1000);
            socket.send(new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName(local), port));
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm constantly getting `GC_FOR_ALLOC` messages in logcat, and allowing the application to run for a period of time will eventually kick the router off, which then needs to be reset. Is there perhaps a better way of sending realtime information over the network?

Comment: Yes use a `Service` but still if you wana send real time data over the network *constantly* then whatever you do sooner or later android os may decide to reset it, if it needs memory

Comment: @Sharpedge Thanks for the quick reply! I'll definitely look into services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GC_FOR_ALLOC` means there was not enough free memory to fulfill an allocation request, so a garbage collection was necessary !

A lot of those in the `Logcat` means that you're doing some memory expensive operation, which will eventually be halted.  When the application's heap has grown as big as it is allowed, then `GC_FOR_ALLOC` won't be able to free any memory, after that the `DVM` throws OutOfMemoryException and halts the application.

You should consider using a `Timer` to delay operations, or if you have some interaction with the `UI Thread` then use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delaymilisecs)` so as to give the `DVM` enough time to allocate enough memory for the next operation.

You can investigate your App's RAM usage and other leaked Objects, check out these official links

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

There is also a document about general strategies for managing your memory consumption in Android:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html